# Сохранение параметров СКД во внешнем отчете

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, есть внешний отчет на СКД, для вывода которого необходимо установить множество параметров(номенклатурные группы, склады и т.п.), что вызывает у пользователя "легкий" приступ недовольства, есть ли возможность сохранять установленные значения параметров и востанавливать их, когда в следующий раз будет открыт отчет?

**1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.15.294) УПП**

Comment: код на 1с умилительный  ))))))))

Comment: Тут кроме запроса кода нет )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

[image: Меню Все действия]

[image: Окно сохранения настроек отчёта]

**UPD.**

```
   Настройки = КомпоновщикНастроек.ПолучитьНастройки();
   Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.УстановитьЗначениеПараметра("НачалоПериода", ТекущаяДата());
   Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.УстановитьЗначениеПараметра("КонецПериода", КонецМесяца(ТекущаяДата()));
```

Потом по старой схеме `МакетКомпоновки  >  ПроцессорКомоновкиДанных > ПроцессорВывода`

Comment: Я имел в виду программно

Comment: Вы меня не совсем праильно поняли. Я хочу чтобы пользователь ввел один раз параметры (например массив складов) и эти параметры сохраняются в какое-то хранилище настроек пользователя(если есть такое). При открытии отчета, эти параметры загружаются из хранилища и устанавливаются в СКД. Каждому пользователю свое хранилище настроек. Если настройки меняются - процедцра повторяется. Это возможно?

Comment: 1. Пользователь после ввода первичных настроек нажимает соответствующие кнопки на рис. 1, при открытии загружает последний сохранённый вариант

2. Ручная работа с ХранилищеПользовательскихНастроекОтчетов. Там есть методы сохранить/загрузить, ключём будет имя вашего внешнего отчёта, так-же надо указать имя пользователя для которого сохранять настройки и имя ключа варианта настроек.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую )